# Two-layered X-Axis in Altair (Python)

Tags: python, visualization, altair

I have a DataFrame consisting of four columns: Year (int64), Month (object/string), Company (object/string), Score (int64).

I want to illustrate the development of the core over the months and years, but I can't figure out how to create this x-axis as shown below with Altair.

```
    Year    Month Company   NPS
0   2019    Jan   Competitor A  29
1   2019    Feb   Competitor B  29
2   2019    Mar   Competitor C  31
...
```

That's what I've tried so far, but it won't work

```
chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
  x=alt.X('Month:N'),
  y=alt.Y('NPS:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0,60])),
  color=alt.Color('company:N', scale=alt.Scale(domain=['Our Company', 'Competitor A', 'Competitor B', 'Competitor C', 'Competitor D'], range=['#000', '#c8c8c8', '#c8c8c8', '#c8c8c8', '#c8c8c8']))
)
```

It gives me this output:

[image]

This below is my goal:

[image]

Comment: Would creating facets with zero spacing as in this example be helpful? https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/violin_plot.html

Comment: No @joelostblom, actually it doesn't change anything. I don't know how to configure the x-axis that it takes both the year and the month and displays it accordingly to the goal above. I added the current output, as you can see above.